# Junittest upload java webflux service

Tags: java, upload, spring-webflux

Good night:

When I try to execute this test, return this error.
`java.lang.NullPointerException: at the height of .map(dataBuffer -> { lines below....`

Attached Test:

```
 @Test
    void testing_1() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        FilePart filePart = BDDMockito.mock(FilePart.class);
        BDDMockito.given(filePart.filename()).willReturn("resources/ejemplo.csv");
        Mockito.when(repo.metodo(any())).thenReturn("Abcd");                
        service.importData(filePart);}
```

Class service:

```
public Flux<String> importData(FilePart filePart) {
        return filePart.content().map(dataBuffer -> { // This line throw NullPointerException
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[dataBuffer.readableByteCount()];
                    dataBuffer.read(bytes);
                    DataBufferUtils.release(dataBuffer);
                    return bytes;})
                .map(t -> {});
}
```

Maybe do you know any way to mock filePart or filePart.content()?

Comment: You need to return a mock from `content()`. That mock will need to use `thenAnswer` to call your lambda.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out.

```
    byte [] dataBufferBytes =  // define your test byte array data here. 
    DataBuffer dataBuffer = Mockito.mock(DataBuffer.class);
    doReturn(dataBuffer).when(filePart).content();
    doReturn(dataBufferBytes).when(dataBuffer).readableByteCount();
```

Besides that, I don't think this test will execute in this way in WebFlux. There is a different test framework all together for testing reactive streams known as `reactor-test`. Try using `StepVerifier` from that framework.

You can find some examples [here](https://www.baeldung.com/reactive-streams-step-verifier-test-publisher)